# Event for JComboBox array and show information at the JLabel Array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

I have the JComboBox  Array and the JLabel Array like this
 What i will do here to make the JLabel return corresponding when I select the values in each JComboBo 
Example when comboBox[0].setSelectItem(4); the label[0] will get the text is 4 
when the comboBox[4].setSelectedItem(2); the lable[4] will get the text is 2

```
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Example extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ItemListener {
    JComboBox[] comboBox = new JComboBox[5];
    JLabel[] label = new JLabel[5];

    public void test() {
        for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
            comboBox[i] = new JComboBox();
            label[i] = new JLabel();
            add(comboBox[i]);
            add(label[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
                comboBox[i].addItem(j);
            }
            comboBox[i].addItemListener(this);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        // What i will do here to make the JLabel return corresponding when I
        // select the values in each JComboBox

        /*
         * Example when comboBox[0].setSelectItem(4); the label[0] will get the
         * text is 4 when the comboBox[4].setSelectedItem(2); the lable[4] will
         * get the text is 2
         */
    }
}
```

Please anyone help me :(

Comment: *"I have the JComboBox Array and the JLabel Array like this"*  Do you have a ***question?***

Comment: What is the question??

Comment: Sorry Everyone, I put the Question into the code, at the bottom in the code block :D

Answer (score 1):

`JComboBox` has method

```
public int getSelectedIndex()
```

Use it to get index, convert the index to string and set to the `JLabel`.

Answer (score 1):

1) You adding your components directly to `JFrame` with help of

`add(comboBox[i]); add(label[i]);` , but in this case your `JFrame` use `BorderLayout` as default, and you always add components to Center position, in this case you will see only one component. [Tutorial for LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

I recommend you to add your labels and comboBoxes to separate panels and then add them to `JFrame`.

2)Your `Example` class implements `ItemListener` and you add it to your `JComboBox`, it's right but in this case you must to loop relevat `JLabel` in `itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)`. Try to add separate listeners to each comboBox with `JLabel` as parametr.

3) Instead of adding each value to comboBox you can use [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox%28E%5B%5D%29) of `JComboBox` with array parametr.

I changed your code examine it:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    JComboBox[] comboBox = new JComboBox[5];
    JLabel[] label = new JLabel[5];

    public void test() {
        JPanel labels = new JPanel();
        JPanel boxes = new JPanel();
        Object[] values = new Object[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
        for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
            comboBox[i] = new JComboBox(values);
            label[i] = new JLabel(" ");
            boxes.add(comboBox[i]);
            labels. add(label[i]);
            comboBox[i].addItemListener(getListener(label[i]));
        }
        getContentPane().add(boxes,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        getContentPane().add(labels,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pack();
    }

    private ItemListener getListener(final JLabel jLabel) {
        return new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
                if(arg0.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    jLabel.setText(((JComboBox)arg0.getSource()).getSelectedItem().toString());
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String...strings ){
        Test test = new Test();
        test.test();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million thanks
that is what i want, really thanks for your supported <3